# Getting state of Numlock in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I am looking for a way to query the state of Numlock in a Silverlight 4 application.

We are doing a Silverlight application for terminals which are equipped with only a numerical keypad (just the numerical block). Unfortunately the device doesn't have an indicator for Numlock. If I could query the state of Numlock I could put an indicator on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Control.IsKeyLocked doesn't appear to be available in Silverlight.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked.aspx

You can apparently detect Caps-lock in Javascript so I can't see why you can't do something similar for numlock. 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Detect_Caps_Lock.aspx

Then you could call your javascript function using silverlight...
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/09/calling-javascript-functions-from-silverlight-2.aspx